# How can my flatpaks inherit gnome themes?

Tags: theme, flatpak, cursor

I am having problems with all the `Flatpak` packages that I install: they don't inherit the themes of cursor and window and use a theme of the windows similar to the predefined one of gnome, and the `Adwaita` cursor, even if I am using a `Breeze-snow`. I didn't do anything at the moment to solve it, because I don't know why do flatpaks behave that way.